# Checking to see if one variable matches a value in another array.

Tags: php, variables, multidimensional-array

I have a variable called $gID, I also have a multi dimensional array with sets of group values.

eg....

```
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [userId] => 3
                [groupId] => 24
                [status] => 1
                [timestamp] => 2012-08-01 20:09:36
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [userId] => 3
                [groupId] => 25
                [status] => 1
                [timestamp] => 2012-08-01 20:08:01
            )

    )
```

What I need to do is search the array and return true if the status = 1 if the [groupId] = $gID

What would the most efficient way to do this be? Any ideas? I thought of doing it in two foreach loops but thought there must be a better way forward.

Cheers Chris

Comment: Why can't you just check for `$data[$gID][status] == 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't worry so much about performance at first. Nonetheless, you can do this with one `foreach`.

```
// simple boolean function
function search_stuff($arr, $gID) {
  foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if ($item['gID'] == $gID && $item['status'] == 1) {
       return false;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

// sample call
var_dump(search_stuff($arr['data'], $gID));
```

I suggest making this a function, for flexibility and ease of maintenance. That way if you find a more performant solution, there's only one place to update.